# How to improve Entity Framework 4.0 large model startup performance?

Tags: performance, optimization, entity-framework-4

On a project with around 350 entities in the EDMX entity model, my team is experiencing lengthly waits when the first query happens and when the first save happens.

When profiling a simple case which runs a few queries and saves, a simple set of steps just to fire a query and save takes minutes.

The first query takes 47% of the overall time just the call that framework method that executes the query.

The first save takes 50% of the overall time just in System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges.

Are there any good options to improve performance - this can be a drain on development time.

(Once the system hits production, it's annoying at startup but not a problem during the ongoing execution)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you use context for the first time it generates mapping model defined in metadata. The option is to [pregenerate this model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896240.aspx) and include pregenerated files in your application (but you must regenerate it each time you modify your EDMX).

Such a big model should be probably divided into multiple smaller models. I hardly believe that 350 entities form single domain which cannot be divided.

Comment: Thanks! It worked well. I ended up using the T4 template genenration methoed linked to in the article you referenced. It reduced my initial query run to less than 5% of the original time and the initial save similarly.  The time cost is shifted to saving the EDMX, but since this is a less frequent operation, significant development time is saved during debugging runs. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2008/06/20/how-to-use-a-t4-template-for-view-generation.aspx

Comment: Your point about splitting models is understood and appreciated.  Interestingly, we previously had separate models, but ended up concluding that a unified model would alleviate some challenges that separate models had introduced and that, for this system, the advantages outweighed the other issues.

Answer (score 1):

A single large EDMX will result in a large ObjectContext. everytime you do `using(var ctx = new YourObjectContext())` it is going to construct a large object, initialize a lot of collections (probably 350 of them) and it is going to make your database operations CPU intensive. You will certainly hit performance challenges when you get high volume traffic.

I would suggest breaking the large WDMX into smaller EDMX and produce different ObjectContexts. You should put small number of logically grouped entities into one ObjectContext.